# Can the sentence "This world is sad" have two meanings?

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

> **"This world is sad."**

Since "sad" can mean either *"saddening (depressing)"* or *"unhappy"*, I think that this sentence I gave can mean either **"This world is saddening."** or **"This world is unhappy."**, am I right? If yes, how can I let the person who is listening to me understand which one I mean when I say that sentence? Is it understood by the context?

For example, let's say I received some bad news about some killings in a country. In this case, if I said **"This world is sad"**, I think it would be understood as **"This world is saddening"**.

Comment: It could have many implied meanings. That is why we add extra words for clarity.

Comment: @user3169 - You are right; _sad_ is nowhere near limited to "two meanings." I like the rather extensive list of synonyms found on [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/sad).

Comment: Also, I think you are looking too hard for a precise meaning.  "This world is sad" doesn't have to literally mean "Everyone in the world is sad" or "This world makes me sad", it can just mean something like "This world is characterized by sadness."

Comment: Thank you for the answers. @J.R. Can I say "This room is sad." for meaning "This room is depressing."? Context: Let's say I have a house. I am sitting in a room with a friend.  That room brings back bad memories. I think in that context I can say it for meaning "depressing" - "saddening". But also in a different context, to be more artistic, I can say it to mean "This room is unhappy" as well, right?

Comment: @FireandIce - Of course you can say, "This room is sad." However, in general, when you use more precise language, there will be less ambiguity in your statement. I think "This room is depressing," or "This room brings back bad memories," are both better than "This room is sad." After all, "This room is sad" could just mean "This room is poorly decorated and in need of a new paint job."

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. I see. As I said, it can mean *"This room is unhappy"* too, can't it?

Comment: @FireandIce - Rooms don't have emotions. Rooms aren't unhappy. That said, rooms can make people feel unhappy, but still, there are many kinds of unhappiness, such as grouchiness, sadness, moroseness, gloominess, and heartbreak. If you told me, "This room is unhappy," I couldn't be sure what you were trying to express.

Comment: @J.R. Of course, but you can say that an object is sad too like in an artistic way. Like *"This room witnessed so many bad incidents. Even it feels depressed."*

Comment: @FireandIce - Sure, but why would you take an emotive, meaningful, descriptive sentence like, _"This room witnessed so many bad incidents, even the room feels depressed"_ and change that to _"This room is unhappy"_? I think it's much better to stick with rich words like _depressing_ instead of words like _sad_ or _unhappy_, which are too vague to describe a room in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

> This world is sad.

The word *sad* in the remark above, for instance, uttered after a series of tragic events (e.g. terrorist attacks) occurs, would likely be interpreted to mean "saddening".

However, if something happens that affects everyone the world over simultaneously, perhaps the death of a noteworthy person, and everyone is seen as mourning that person's death, one might say

> The whole world is sad.

and thereby employ *the whole world* as a metaphor for "the people living in this world", with *sad* meaning "unhappy".

That said, either sentence could be used for either of the described scenarios. The first one is most commonly used hyperbolically (in exaggeration).

To conclude: the word *sad* has multiple meanings (it's said to be polysemous), and which interpretation will be the salient (conspicuous) one is context-dependent.